# Bootstrap fixed-top navbar

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am building a SPA with boostrap, the navbar is a fixed-top.
when I add content it is cut off by the navbar unless I specify the element margin-top to 58px or using the styles below helps out but not sustainable as I have many rows on the application.

```
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left:  5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
} */
```

[image: the full row divs don'nt show up].

Answer (score 0):

Navbar must be out of the container with a padding-top

```
<nav>
    ...
</nav>

<div class="container pt-5">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: yes it is..<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div container>

    <flash-messages></flash-messages>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>